# Object variable not set (Error 91) in a class macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I get the error 91 in the following code and I cannot figure it out!

I think the problem is occurring when I try to declare a class module `clsPeril` inside another class module `xxxLoB`. I think I have over engineered this!

Module is:

```
Public Sub SomeSub()
    Dim objPolicy As New xxxPolicy

    objPolicy.xxxLoB.FLEA.Attl = 10  <---- error is here
    objPolicy.xxxLoB.Flood = 100
End Sub
```

Class module `xxxPolicy`:

```
Dim objLoB As New xxxLoB

Public Property Get xxxLoB() As xxxLoB
    Set xxxLoB = objLoB
End Property

Public Property Set xxxLoB(ByVal objNewValue As xxxLoB)
   Set objLoB = objNewValue
End Property
```

Class module `xxxLoB`:

```
Dim dblFLEA As clsPeril
Dim dblFlood As Double

Public Property Get FLEA() As clsPeril
    FLEA.Attl = dblFLEA
End Property
Public Property Let FLEA(ByVal FLEANewValue As clsPeril)
    dblFLEA = FLEANewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Flood() As Double
    Flood = dblFlood
End Property
Public Property Let Flood(ByVal FloodNewValue As Double)
    dblFlood = FloodNewValue
End Property
```

Class module `clsPeril`:

```
Public Attl As Double
Public Large As Double
Public Cat As Double
Public Excess As Double
Public SI As Double
```

Comment: You never instantiate `dblFLEA` inside `xxxLoB`, but even if you did, you never return it from the `Property Get FLEA`.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  I am a vb rookie - how do I fix this?